# How Do I Align My CSS Drop Down Menu In The Center?

Tags: html, css

I am not sure how to align this drop down menu to the center. It just stays to the left. Also how do I change the distance it is from the top? Any ideas? Thank you ahead of time.

```css
ul {
    margin:0px;
    padding:0px;
}
ul li {
    background-color:black;
    border:1px solid white;
    width:200px;
    height:30px;
    line-height:30px;
    float:left;
    text-align:center;
    list-style:none;
}
ul li a {
    color:white;
    text-decoration:none;
    display:block;
}
ul li a:hover {
    background-color:red;
}
ul li ul li {
    display:none;
}
ul li:hover ul li {
    display:block;
}
```

```html
<div class="dropmenu">
    <ul>
        <li> <a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li> <a href="#">Goals</a></li>
        <li> <a href="#">Coursework</a>
        <ul>
            <li> <a href="#">CSIS 1430</a></li>
            <li> <a href="#">ENGR 1050</a></li>
            <li> <a href="#">HUMA 1100</a></li>
        </ul>
        </li>
        <li> <a href="#">Outside</a></li>
        <li> <a href="#">Resume</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: What do you mean by center? Horizontally? And only "CourseWork" has a dropdown

Comment: heres your code on a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/dx747d4f/ which bit do you want to stay center? The one where you hover and it appears?

Comment: `ul{display:table;margin:auto;}` should center the whole menu bar.

Answer (score 3):

You should use `display: inline-block;` on the `li` items. I also update the CSS code for the dropdown, that way it will be center aligned too.

```css
ul {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    list-style: none;
    text-align: center;
}

ul li {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 200px;
    line-height: 30px;
    background: black;
}

ul a {
    display: block;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: white;
}

ul a:hover {
    background-color:red;
}

ul li ul {
    position: absolute;
    top: 100%;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -100px;
    display:none;
}

ul li:hover ul {
    display:block;
}
```

```html
<ul>
    <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Coursework</a>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">CSIS 1430</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">ENGR 1050</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">HUMA 1100</a></li>
    </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Outside</a></li>
</ul>
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: That is overall better answer.

Answer (score 3):

You actually don't want them all to pull-right (which utilizes the css: float: right;).

You have to understand what float: right does.  Float right means, float to the right to the last inline element.

So if you have object 1, 2, 3, 4 each floating right in this order, you'll end up having 4, 3, 2, 1 (1 floats to the right, 2 floats right to the last inline element, which is 1, etc).

What you want is to wrap the whole thing in a container, and have each element float left.

```
<div class="container">
<div class-"item">1</div>
<div class-"item">2</div>
<div class-"item">3</div>
<div class-"item">4</div>
</div>

<style>
.item {
float: left;
}
.container {
float: right;
}
</style>
```

Comment: A quick edit to this to make it cleaner on the page.  You want to also make sure you clear: both after you do all these floating (otherwise you'll end up having a height issue).  You can do this by wrapping this whole thing in bootstrap's class "row" (what row does is put a clear:both after all the elements)

Answer (score 1):

Add style for your dropmenu class...

```
.dropmenu { width: 1010px; margin-top: 20px; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto; }
```

Answer (score 1):

Change your div tag to this

```
<div class="dropmenu" style="margin-top: 50px; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto; width: 1010px;">
```

The `margin-top: 50px` indicates how far from the top you want the div to be.

Answer (score 0):

Not a full answer, but on the fly try this.
Remove all floats if any, change or add display:inline-block; to the li elements.

Comment: I don't think that will change much

Comment: You think wrong?
https://jsfiddle.net/dx747d4f/3/

it's your JS fiddle as a base. thanks for that as It simplified the box model on it...

To expand on why that is - float takes elements out of the box model, Display:inline-block; lives the elements within the box model so that a simple Text-align:center; on the parent element actually "centers" them - all the while keeping them in-line.

I'm not sure how cross browser compatible this is, as it's not what I'd do on an actual website anyway.

Comment: It clearly provided an answer. Look at the JS fiddle.

Answer (score 0):

You can add padding-left and move it to the center:

```
     ul
        {
            margin:0px;
            padding:0px;
            padding-left: 50px;// or any bigger number and you will see that it'll move to the right
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add margin-left:auto and margin-right:auto in .dropdownmenu class.

I have modified your code to achieve this.

```css
.dropdownmenu {
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
}
ul {
    margin:0px;
    padding:0px;
}
ul li {
    background-color:black;
    border:1px solid white;
    width:200px;
    height:30px;
    line-height:30px;
    float:left;
    text-align:center;
    list-style:none;
}
ul li a {
    color:white;
    text-decoration:none;
    display:block;
}
ul li a:hover {
    background-color:red;
}
ul li ul li {
    display:none;
}
ul li:hover ul li {
    display:block;
}
```

```html
<div class="dropmenu">
    <ul>
        <li> <a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li> <a href="#">Goals</a></li>
        <li> <a href="#">Coursework</a>
        <ul>
            <li> <a href="#">CSIS 1430</a></li>
            <li> <a href="#">ENGR 1050</a></li>
            <li> <a href="#">HUMA 1100</a></li>
        </ul>
        </li>
        <li> <a href="#">Outside</a></li>
        <li> <a href="#">Resume</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```